# Binding data between Dictionary and CheckedListBox using Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, dictionary, checkedlistbox

I would like to bind the `Values` of a `Dictionnary <string, List<string>>` in a `CheckedListBox` in C#. The purpose is to display some user selectable text in the listbox and retieve the associated keys if selected.

I found snippets using `DataSource` and `DisplayMember` propertys (which seem to be part of `ListBox`) but I just can't figure out this mess in my head. Moreover, there is a `DataBindings` property that intelli sense offers instead of the two others.

I don't know if it's possible or not to do that because I saw a lot of similar threads but for ListBox or ComboBox but that didn't work for me. I have an empty check box followed by "Collection" on my listbox with no further update.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See [CheckedListBox checked list item property binding to field in a class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23959497/719186)

Comment: Thanks for the link, very useful! However it doesn't solve my problem...